# How could Asuras get boons from God?

Tags: asuras

I think one need to have the purest heart to get a Darshana of God, let alone a boon from God.

But how Mahisasura, Hiranyakashipu and many more Asuras got boons from God with all their evil intensions?

Comment: "I think one need to have the purest heart to get a Darshana of God, let alone a boon from God." - Nothing like that. your presumptions are wrong.

Comment: Then what? Does devotion enough, even if one has evil intentions?

Comment: Desires are enough to bring about anything. Intentions behind desires don't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Irrespective of one's motive, if one does sufficient austerities or tapas then he/she is bound to get the rewards.

Whatever his intention was will not prevent him from getting the rewards.

Here are a few verses from the Manu Smriti which talk about this overwhelming power of austerity.

> 11.234. All the bliss of gods and men is declared by the sages to whom the Veda was revealed, **to have austerity for its root, austerity for
>   its middle, and austerity for its end**
>
> 11.237. Medicines, good health, learning, and the various divine stations **are attained by austerities alone; for austerity is the means
>   of gaining them.**
>
> 11.238. **Whatever is hard to be traversed, whatever is hard to be attained, whatever is hard to be reached, whatever is hard to be
>   performed, all (this) may be accomplished by austerities; for
>   austerity (possesses a power) which it is difficult to surpass.**
>
> 11.240. **Insects, snakes, moths, bees, birds and beings, bereft of motion, reach heaven by the power of austerities.**
>
> 11.243. The lord, Prajapati, **created these Institutes (of the sacred law) by his austerities alone**; the sages likewise obtained (the
>   revelation of) the Vedas through their austerities.

So, when the intention will also eventually matter in deciding the overall fate of the Asuras but they are not to be deprived of the fruits of performing severe austerities by any means.

Hence, they get the boons that they won with their severe tapas. God will always grant boons once he decides that this Asura has done the sufficient amount of austerity required to get the boons he is asking for.